# Help for find Camera Datasheet or interface to st32f103

Tags: stm32, datasheet, camera, interface, protocol

I want to use of S302's Camera(the S302 is a mobile phone with a good camera) and interface it st32f103 but, unfortunately I can't find any datasheet for it. Also, I can find the schematic of Phone and can to some things of it but I think it's not enough.

[image: back]

[image: front]

Where can I find the datasheet of the camera? If we can't find the datasheet then help me until to use of it. On the back of camera wrote:

SAGEM

[image: camera's factory]

I think I can to use I2C for interface it because you can find some I2C's pins in the schematic. look:

[image: Schematic]

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might want to consider the bandwidth requirements for anything other than still images, an HD camera generates more data per frame than most small micros can happily handle without external RAM or just taking along time. Multi-megapixel ones generate huge amounts of data per frame which takes a lot of processing / compression to be usable.

Comment: The STM32 is likely unsuitable for driving this camera

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not saying that you will NOT find this data sheet.  Do keep trying.  But in general, data sheets for SOC's, cameras etc. that are used in the handset market are generally only released on NDA and are not generally available.

You can see this on sites like Spark fun that sell the modules but can't supply the data sheets.

However, there are a couple things you can do.  These devices typically are on MIPI interfaces and also conform to standard I2C or I2S interface's with semi-similar register mappings.  the electrical interfaces will be standardized, it's the register mappings and uses that might be hard to determine.  However, a lot of these cameras are supported under Android which is open source, there will be generic camera register mappings in that source code.  Some of the cameras driver modules are proprietary, but people have published them anyways.

Look around for these forums for guidance.